# Swift - Struct of Structs

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

Currently working on a project that information on different materials and I'm trying to figure out how to combine the individual swift files into one overall object to work with.

MaterialOne.swift:

```
struct MaterialOne {

    let name = ("Material 1")
    let otherData = 13.91

    struct RelatedData {

        let relatedData1 = 49.44
        let relatedData2 = 0.0
        ...
        let relatedData9 = 35.46
    }
}
```

MaterialTwo.swift:

```
struct MaterialTwo {

    let name = ("Material 2")
    let otherData = 34.21

    struct RelatedData {

        let relatedData1 = 45.42
        let relatedData1 = 45.42
        ...
        let relatedData9 = 70.46
    }
}
```

Combined.swift:

```
struct Combined {
    let materialOne = MaterialOne()
    let materialTwo = MaterialTwo()
}
let listOfMaterials = [ // doesn't compile.
    materialOne,
    materialTwo
]
```

If I then create a variable from the Combined struct;

```
let combinedData = Combined()
```

I can tap into combinedData.Material#.name and combinedData.Material#.otherData. But I can not tap into combinedData.Material#.RelatedData.

How can I tap into the RelatedData struct? And how can I add the materials into one struct/array so all the data can be drawn from the same source when needed?

Comment: There is no need to make RelatedData as a nested structure. Make it independent.

Comment: I can do that. I just thought it would be clearer if it was nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply having nested structs does not make them accesible in the surrounding struct. What you need to say is something like this:

```
struct MaterialOne {
    let name = "Material 1"
    let otherData = 13.91
    let related = RelatedData(relatedData1: 49.44, relatedData2: 0, relatedData9: 35.46)

    struct RelatedData {

        let relatedData1: Double
        let relatedData2: Double
        // ...
        let relatedData9: Double

    }
}
```

Also, this

```
let listOfMaterials = [ // doesn't compile.
    materialOne,
    materialTwo
]
```

doesn't compile because all elements in an array need to be of the same type. `MaterialOne` and `MaterialTwo` are unrelated, so you get this error.

Comment: Gotcha ya. I’ll rework the nested struct. - Since the data structures are the same, I suppose I should be able to make a struct or type Material, and then initialize the different materials as that type.?

Comment: Yes, do that. This will also allow you to have arrays of `Material` instances easily.